# In vscode, how to debug on a compute node of slurm cluster?

Tags: visual-studio-code, gpu, cluster-computing, remote-debugging, slurm

Here is my dilemma

1. First, log in login-node via remote-ssh in vscode
2. Then apply a compute-node with gpu
3. If i debug the python program, it would go to the login-node which is not allowed.

Now, i can only debug the program through print which is veryyy inconvenient.

So, iwant to know is there any solution?

Comment: @kaienfr Have you solve this problem, i just notice you have asked a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61283653/how-to-remote-debugging-on-a-cluster-node-from-vscode

Comment: Have you over found a solution to this? I have the same issue...

Answer (score 2):

You can try this course of action:

1. login and apply for a compute-node with gpu
2. set a configuration for that gpu node in your `.ssh/config` with a `ProxyJump` through the login node
3. log in gpu-node via remote-ssh in vscode

Comment: i have already tried this method, it seems that the gpu-nodes have its own password

Comment: Maybe try using a public key for authentication instead of a password (you can then load the private key into your local ssh-agent to avoid having to enter anything manually on each connection).